# Read a Folder's subfolders and files in these subfolders using Windows cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working on a batch script which reads a file and "find and replace" this character "╡" to "µ"

So far I was able to write following code:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

chcp 65001

Set "Pattern=╡"
Set "Replace=µ"

For %%# in ("E:\CopiedVault\*") Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

The problem I am facing is how I don't know how this script can be modified ,by which it can read subfolders of folder "CopiedVault", and then can find and replace files and their names.

This script works perfect if it is able to find the file.

Comment: Try with `for /r "E:\CopiedVault" %%# in (*) do (`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dir /s /b E:\CopiedVault
```

inside a forloop and for each occurance rename the file.